# Mount a directory on Linux Server as a Network Drive on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, networking, drive

I am trying to figure out if it is at all possible to mount a specific folder structure from another (Linux) system as a network drive on Windows.
In this case I have users on a virtual windows desktop and they currently use a FTP client to access our file server. I would like to simplify this process by mounting their folder structure directly as a network drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either map your FTP [as a network location](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/work-with-files-ftp-site#1TC=windows-7), or configure a `samba` server on you linux box.